# all post's information displayed when using each do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, associations, each

I have "advices" which belong to a user. Users have many advices.
I try to show each advice's name of the current user in the view which works fine. However I don't know why all others advice's informations are also displayed in the end of the advice's names list (Advice id, name, content, created_at, updated_at, user_id). Thank you for helping.

View :

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= current_user.advices.each do |c| %>
    <ul>
      <li><%= c.name %> - <%= c.content %></li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
  <% else %>
  <p> you have to log in</p>
<% end %>
```

controller :

```
  def index
    @advices = Advice.all
  end
```

Models :

```
class Advice < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :advices
end
```

schema :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160329192355) do

  create_table "advices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "reseau"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "reseau"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this bit?

```
<%= current_user.advices.each do |c| %>
```

really should be

```
<% current_user.advices.each do |c| %>
```

You've been outputting the array with your advices.

Comment: Indeed... Thank you. I have no idea why i put this =

Comment: Accepting my answer would be a nice thing to do then ;-)

Oh, and sooner or later you'll forget to add the `=` for a `form_tag` or `fields_for`. Remember them now :)

Comment: Sure, I am pretty new on Stack thank for for remind me =)